# How to remove nesting from this ternary operation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested

```
Object.values(filter).filter(item =>
 Array.isArray(item)
 ? item.length > 0
 : typeof item === "boolean"
 ? item === true 
 : item !== null
).length ? filterIcon : unFilledIcon"
```

Here I want to remove the nesting of this ternary operator. Also I want to reduce my cognitive complexity along with it.

Comment: What's wrong with using regular `if`s?

Comment: @VLAZ Actually I want to reduce cognitive complexity also so if I add an if-else statement then cognitive complexity will remain the same.

Comment: @YashShah the cognitive complexity will be vastly reduced by ifs

Comment: You can use early exit: `if (Array.isArray(item)) return !!item.length; ...`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @YashShah I'd disagree. It's much harder to parse a chained conditional operator than a series of `if` statements. But if you're looking at a metric, then replacing nested conditions with others that are still conditions will still give you the same complexity number. Because the number of conditions and thus code branches remains the same. You can extract the logic to a lookup which does reduce the complexity analysis number but in this case it'd probably worth re-writing the whole thing, rather than shuffling some conditions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use early exit:

```
Object.values(filter).filter(item => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) return !!item.length;
  if (typeof item === 'boolean') return item;
  return item !== null;
}).length ? filterIcon : unFilledIcon"
```

and combine `item === true` and `item !== null` with `!!item`:

```
Object.values(filter).filter(item => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) return !!item.length;
  return !!item;
}).length ? filterIcon : unFilledIcon"
```

In the second code results are different, e.g. if undefined or empty strings are involved.

Comment: `item === true` and `item !== null` are not strictly equal to `!!item`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use regular `if`s to make the logic vastly more readable:

```
const isFilter = Object.values(filter).some(item => {
  if (Array.isArray(item))
    return item.length > 0;

  if (typeof item === "boolean")
    return item === true;

  return item !== null;
});

if (isFilter)
  return filterIcon;

return unFilledIcon;
```

The `.filter().length` is also replaced with `.some()` as you just want to find if there are any matches, not what those matches are.

Comment: `return item != null;` should catch undefined AND null

Comment: @mplungjan I'm using OP's code. I'd rather not make assumptions. Perhaps `undefined` is correct. Or not possible.